# Remove object from array knowing its id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
var myArr;
```

Let’s say that on page load it contains 10 objects with the following structure:

```
{
  Id: …,
  Name: …
}
```

How can I remove an object from `myArr` by its `Id`?

Comment: find the index of the object that has that id within your array and remove that from the array

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try like this

```
var id = 2;
var list = [{
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'a'
}, {
  Id: 2,
  Name: 'b'
}, {
  Id: 3,
  Name: 'c'
}];
var index = list.map(x => {
  return x.Id;
}).indexOf(id);

list.splice(index, 1);
console.log(list);
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/bxu2j7u0/117/)**</kbd>

Or you can utilize [**.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Like this

```
var id = 2;
var list = [{
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'a'
}, {
  Id: 2,
  Name: 'b'
}, {
  Id: 3,
  Name: 'c'
}];
var lists = list.filter(x => {
  return x.Id != id;
})
console.log(lists);
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6y8pmzrn/)</kbd>

Answer (score 28):

Two solutions, one evolve creating new instance and one changes the instance of your array.

Filter:

```
idToRemove = DESIRED_ID;

myArr = myArr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.Id != idToRemove;
});
```

As you can see, the `filter` method returns new instance of the filtered array.

Second option is to find the index of the item and then remove it with `splice`:

```
idToRemove = DESIRED_ID;

index = myArr.map(function(item) {
    return item.Id
}).indexOf(idToRemove);

myArr.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

can you try

```
newArray = myArr
  .filter(function(element) {
    return element.id !== thisId;
  });
```