# How to remove elements from an array by element id that is in another array?

Tags: javascript

Example

```
const arr1 = [{id:1,name:'qwerty'},{id:2,name:'qwerty'}]
const arr2 = [{id:1,name:'qwerty'},{id:2,name:'qwerty'},{id:3,name:'qwerty'},{id:4,name:'qwerty'}]
```

I need to remove all the elements by id from the arr1 that are in the arr2

result

```
const arr2 = [{id:3,name:'qwerty'},{id:4,name:'qwerty'}]
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: [Convert array of objects into array of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34309090/4642212) (first Google result for `site:stackoverflow.com js array of objects to array of ids`) and [remove object from js array knowing its Id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34336633/4642212) (first Google result for `site:stackoverflow.com js remove array elements by id`). Then use [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove object from js array knowing it's Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336633/remove-object-from-js-array-knowing-its-id)

Answer (score 3):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with all `id` from `arr1` and filter `arr2`.

This approach

```
result = arr2.filter(
    (ids => ({ id }) => !ids.has(id))
    (arr1.reduce((s, { id }) => s.add(id), new Set))
);
```

utilize a closure with an IIFE ([immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) over an instance of a `Set` with

```
arr1.reduce((s, { id }) => s.add(id), new Set)
```

and this is the value for `ids`

```
(ids => callback)(instanceOfSet)
```

The callback consist only a destructuring for `id` and a check with [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)

```
({ id }) => !ids.has(id)
```

```js
const
    arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'qwerty' }, { id: 2, name: 'qwerty' }],
    arr2 = [{ id: 1, name: 'qwerty' }, { id: 2, name: 'qwerty' }, { id: 3, name: 'qwerty' }, { id: 4, name: 'qwerty' }],
    result = arr2.filter(
        (ids => ({ id }) => !ids.has(id))
        (arr1.reduce((s, { id }) => s.add(id), new Set))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: wow! Super answer!:) Nina could you, please, explain how does `ids` work? and why this row works `(arr1.reduce((s, { id }) => s.add(id), new Set)` at first? and only then this row `(ids => ({ id }) => !ids.has(id))` is executed? Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: @StepUp, please see edit.

Comment: Thanks! It is really awesome! Great!:)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your required result by using `filter` and `findIndex` array prototype.

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1,name:'qwerty'},{id:2,name:'qwerty'}];
const arr2 = [{id:1,name:'qwerty'},{id:2,name:'qwerty'},{id:3,name:'qwerty'},{id:4,name:'qwerty'}];

const res = arr2.filter(value => arr1.findIndex(x => x.id === value.id) === -1);
console.log(res);
```

### Update

The same result could be gained by using `find` instead of `findIndex`.

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1,name:'qwerty'},{id:2,name:'qwerty'}];
const arr2 = [{id:1,name:'qwerty'},{id:2,name:'qwerty'},{id:3,name:'qwerty'},{id:4,name:'qwerty'}];

const res = arr2.filter(value => !arr1.find(x => x.id === value.id));
console.log(res);
```